# jQuery: Trouble with draggable across cloned elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui

I'm trying to implement:

1. User drags a draggable `li` to a droppable `li`.
2. The original `li` is no longer draggable
3. A new `li` is cloned from the original `li`, and is appended to the droppable `li`.

I can't get it to work.

```
function moveToTerm(original_course, helper, term) {

 var cloned_course = original_course.clone(true);

 original_course.addClass('already-scheduled');

 original_course.draggable('disable');
 cloned_course.draggable();

 cloned_course.appendTo(term).hide().fadeIn('slow');
}
```

This works fine, except now the cloned_course is not draggable.

A droppable `li`:

```
    <li class="term ui-droppable">
        <strong>Fall 2010</strong>
        <li class="course">Computing Cultures</li>

        <!-- this course was just dropped. I want it to be draggable but it's not -->
        <li class="course ui-draggable" style="display: list-item;">New Media and Society</li>
    </li>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

What does

```
cloned_course.appendTo(term).hide().fadeIn('slow').draggable();
```

do? I suspect `draggable()` only works on elements that have been attached to the DOM.

Comment: Mmm that sounds like it would have worked, but unfortunately `cloned_course` is still not draggable.